# How to build Meld on Ubuntu?

Tags: compiling, meld

I am attempting to build the latest version of Meld on Ubuntu 20.10.

I have followed the instructions at https://github.com/GNOME/meld, ensuring I have the necessary packages for my system.

```
# Enabled "source code" in Sources & Updates.
sudo apt install git build-essential meson ninja-build gettext libgtk-3-dev python-gi-dev python3-cairo-dev appstream-util libgtksourceview-4-dev
sudo apt-get build-dep meld

git clone https://github.com/GNOME/meld.git
cd meld
meson _build
cd _build
ninja
ninja install
```

Everything goes fine, but when I attempt to run meld, I get the following error

```
cd ~
meld
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/meld", line 97, in <module>
    import meld.conf  # noqa: E402
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meld'
```

I suspect this has something to do with *where* the files were installed on my system.

I can see that meld was installed to `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/` while I was expecting it to install to `/usr/share`.

Additionally, I was expecting the executable to be placed in `/usr/bin` but it is in `/usr/local/bin`.
which meld
/usr/local/bin/meld

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Analysis

There are some issues with the method from official README.

Moreover - following [PKGBUILD](https://github.com/archlinux/svntogit-packages/blob/packages/meld/trunk/PKGBUILD) from ArchLinux on Ubuntu with steps below

> ```
> cd /tmp
> git clone https://github.com/GNOME/meld.git
> cd meld
> python3 setup.py build
> sudo python3 setup.py --no-update-icon-cache --no-compile-schemas install --prefix=/usr/local --optimize=1
> ```

does not lead to positive result either. It ends with already seen error:

> ```
> $ meld
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "/usr/local/bin/meld", line 97, in <module>
>    import meld.conf  # noqa: E402
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'meld'
> ```

### Solution

We need to utilize the [deb-src package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/groovy/meld) building procedure to latest source code from git repository.

In step-by-step style it will look as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential gettext libgtk-3-dev python-gi-dev python3-cairo-dev appstream-util libgtksourceview-4-dev dpkg-dev python3-pytest
sudo apt-get build-dep meld

cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/GNOME/meld.git
cd meld

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/meld/meld_3.20.2-2.debian.tar.xz
tar -xf meld_3.20.2-2.debian.tar.xz
mv meld_3.20.2-2.debian.tar.xz ../

sed -i "s|meld.1|data/meld.1|" debian/meld.manpages
sed -i "s|3.20.2-2|$(git describe --tags | sed 's/-/+/g')|" debian/changelog

dpkg-buildpackage -b -uc -us
```

then finally install the package with:

```
sudo apt-get install ../meld_3*_all.deb
```

and check its version:

> ```
> $ meld --version
> meld 3.21.1
> ```

Comment: See update above. I have built the deb-package using pybuild. Did comments cleanup. The method is applicable for 20.04 LTS. So I would recommend to continue using it, to get long support cycle.

Comment: I really appreciate you going through the extra trouble to figure this out. It works flawlessly! Did you mean `gdebi` or `dpkg -i` for the install command? (In my case, I also needed to install dependencies `gir1.2-gtksource-3.0`, `libgtksourceview-3.0-1`, and `libgtksourceview-3.0-common`).

Comment: The `dpkg -i` do not resolve dependencies. So `gdebi` / `gdebi-gtk` or `apt / apt-get` are better. You are welcome. I would recommend to remove unneeded comments above. It was interesting investigation.